# Automatic unfold small folds

Tags: vim

Is there a way to automatic unfold small folds (<10 lines) when using foldmethod=syntax?

I understand that there would be the option to use

```
set foldminlines=10
```

But if I use this setting, I can't fold these parts even if I want to do so later on.

**EDIT**

Thanks to **Ingo Karkat** my config now does what I want it to do.

```
au BufReadPre * if !exists('b:folddict') | let b:folddict = {} | endif
function! s:UnfoldSmallFolds( count )
  if empty(b:folddict)
    "fill list
    let l:_none = s:checkInnerFolds(['1',line('$')], a:count)
  else
    "folddict should be filled by now
    " check if lnum is in fold
    let l:index = s:checkFoldIndex(keys(b:folddict), getpos('.')[1])
    if l:index != 0
      "check if open -> close
      if b:folddict[l:index] == 1
        foldclose
        let b:folddict[l:index] = 0
      else
        foldopen
        let b:folddict[l:index] = 1
        let l:_none = s:checkInnerFolds(split(l:index,'-'),a:count)
      endif
    endif
  endif
endfunction

function! s:checkInnerFolds(index,count)
  let l:lnum = a:index[0]
  while l:lnum <= a:index[1]
    if foldclosed(l:lnum) == -1
      let l:lnum += 1
      continue
    endif

    let l:endLnum = foldclosedend(l:lnum)
    let l:innerIndex = l:lnum."-".l:endLnum
    if has_key(b:folddict,l:innerIndex)
      if b:folddict[l:innerIndex] == 1
        foldopen
        let l:_none = s:checkInnerFolds(l:innerIndex,a:count)
      endif
    else                        
      let b:folddict[l:innerIndex] = 0
      if l:endLnum - l:lnum < a:count
        execute printf('%d,%dfoldopen!', l:lnum, l:endLnum)
        let b:folddict[l:innerIndex] = 1
        let l:_none = s:checkInnerFolds(l:innerIndex,a:count)
      endif
    endif
    let l:lnum = l:endLnum + 1
  endwhile
endfunction


function! s:checkFoldIndex(folds, pos)
  let l:retLine = ['0','0']
  for line in a:folds
    let l:splitLine = split(line,'-')
    if a:pos >= l:splitLine[0] && a:pos <= l:splitLine[1]
      if a:pos-l:splitLine[0] < a:pos-l:retLine[0]
        let l:retLine = l:splitLine
      endif
    endif
  endfor
  return join(l:retLine,"-")
endfunction
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done with a custom function that checks all closed folds and opens those having few lines, like this:

```
" [count]z<r        Open all small folds that contain up to 3 / [count] lines.
function! s:UnfoldSmallFolds( count )
    let l:openCnt = 0
    let l:lnum = 1
    while l:lnum <= line('$')
        if foldclosed(l:lnum) == -1
            let l:lnum += 1
            continue
        endif

        let l:endLnum = foldclosedend(l:lnum)
        if l:endLnum - l:lnum < a:count
            execute printf('%d,%dfoldopen!', l:lnum, l:endLnum)
            let l:openCnt += 1
        endif
        let l:lnum = l:endLnum + 1
    endwhile

    if l:openCnt == 0
        echo printf('No small folds over up to %d lines found', a:count)
    else
        echo printf('%d folds opened', l:openCnt)
    endif
endfunction
nnoremap <silent> z<r :<C-u>call <SID>UnfoldSmallFolds(v:count ? v:count : 3)<CR>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I modified your code a bit to keep track of already visited buffers. So when I close a inner fold shorter than v:count, close the outer fold and then open that fold again, the inner fold remains closed.

Comment: +1 I didn't think of using while traverse all folds... nice idea! learned from you again. thank you.